# Haskell foldr for lists

Tags: haskell

Given the following example

```
foldr(\ x y -> ........
```

if the input is a list for example [1,2,3]

what is x and what is y?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at the type for `foldr`.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Since you're providing the function that uses `x` and `y`, you can see from the type that x will be a value from your list (`[1,2,3]`), and y must be the accumulator value, which you initialize with the second parameter to `foldr`.

Comment: `let result :: b ; result = foldr (\(x :: a) -> \(y::b) -> undefined :: b) (undefined :: b) ([1,2,3] :: [a])`

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `foldr` is

```
foldr f z []     = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

You can just apply it directly in your example:

```
foldr (\x y -> foo x y) z [1,2,3]
=
(\x y -> foo x y) 1 (foldr (\x y -> foo x y) z [2,3])
=
foo 1 (foldr (\x y -> foo x y) z [2,3])
```

So `x` is `1` and `y` is `foldr (\x y ...) z [2,3])`.

In general you can think of `foldr f z` as replacing every `(:)` in a list with `f`, and the `[]` with `z`. So `foldr f z [a,b,c,d]` = `f a (f b (f c (f d z)))` (since `[a,b,c,d]` = `(:) a ((:) b ((:) c ((:) d [])))`.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this is the functional definition of foldr, and that it isn't necessarily implemented this way.

Comment: Yes, but this definition (from the Report) is sufficient for reasoning about `foldr`'s semantics.

Comment: I know its bit odd to respond a question months later.. but isn't foldr starting folding from right? Isn't the first step is f 3 z?

Comment: @NobWong: There is no "first step" as such, but there's an outermost redex, which involves the leftmost element. The "right" in "right fold" means that it's associated from the right, so `foldr (*) z [a,b,c]` is `a * (b * (c * z))` -- note that multiplication by the *first* (leftmost) element is outermost. I recommend looking at the definition and evaluating a few `foldr`s (and `foldl`s) by hand.